# printing Arabic text using prn File on TSC TC200

Tags: c#, printing, arabic

I am using a c# code to create prn file and  print on the TSC TC200 barcode label printer. However when I try to print arabic  characters, it does not print properly. I have downloaded the arabtype.ttf on the flash memory of printer but it still print the unicode and not the actual characters.

Here is my prn sample file:-

```
<xpml><page quantity='0' pitch='40.0 mm'></xpml>SIZE 59.10 mm, 40 mm
GAP 3 mm, 0 mm
DIRECTION 0,0
REFERENCE 0,0
OFFSET 0 mm
SET PEEL OFF
SET CUTTER OFF
SET PARTIAL_CUTTER OFF
<xpml></page></xpml><xpml><page quantity='1' pitch='40.0 mm'></xpml>SET TEAR 
ON
CLS
CODEPAGE 1252
TEXT 460,214,"ROMAN.TTF",180,1,12,"_orderDd"
TEXT 205,214,"ROMAN.TTF",180,1,12,"_orderSh"
TEXT 433,300,"arabtype.TTF",180,20,20,"ام محمد لعجم"
BARCODE 441,76,"128M",25,0,180,4,8,"!104_ordId"
TEXT 284,44,"ROMAN.TTF",180,1,12,"_ordId"
TEXT 457,136,"ROMAN.TTF",180,1,12,"_ptlId"
TEXT 217,136,"ROMAN.TTF",180,1,12,"_orderBox"
BAR 4,224, 470, 3
BAR 4,90, 470, 3
PRINT 1,1
<xpml></page></xpml><xpml><end/></xpml>
```

if I create a prn  using bartender and use arabic fonts, the line with arabic text gets converted to the following

```
BITMAP 49,236,48,48,1,ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÀ  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÀ  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÀ  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÀ  ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿü ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÀÿÿÿÿÿÿÿàÿ€ÿ€ÿþ ÿøÿÿÿÿÿð ?ø?ðð ð?ÿø?ÿÁÿ ÿƒÿÿÿ þ þ þ  À ÿÿÿÿÀ ø?ðð  ðÿø?ÿÁü ÿƒÿÿþ  þ ü  þ  € ?ÿÿÿÿ€ ø?ðð  ðÿø?ÿÁø  ÿƒÿÿü  ~ ø ~    ÿÿÿÿüø?ðð ~ðÿø?ÿÁøÀƒÿÿøà>>øÀ~øøÿÿÿÿÇÿø?ððÿðÿø?ÿÁüð?ƒÿÿøð?þð?ðþüþÿÿÿÿÿÿø?ððÿðÿø?ÿÁÿÿð?ƒÿÿð?øÿðøþþÿþÿÿÿÿÿÿƒø?ððÿðÿø?ÿÁÿÿø?ƒÿÿðüÿðÿþþÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿø?ððÿðÿø?ÿÁÿÿøƒÿÿàüÿðÿþþÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÁø?ððþðÿø?ÿÁÿÿüƒÿÿàÿþÿð?ÿþþÿÿƒÿÿÿÿÿÿÁø?ððþð@ÿø?ÿÁÿÿüƒÿÿàÿþÿð?ÿþþÿÿƒÿÿÿÿÿÿÁø?ððøð`ø?ÿÁÿÿüƒÿÿàÿþÿøÿþþÿÿƒÿÿÿÿÿÿÁø?ððàð`ø?ÿÁÿÿüƒÿÿàÿþÿøÿþþÿÿƒÿÿÿÿ  ø?ðð ?ðp?ø?ÿÁð  ƒÿÿàÿþÿü þþÿÿƒÿÿÿÿ  ø?ðð  ðxø?ÿÁð  ƒÿÿàÿþÿÿ þþÿÿƒÿÿÿÿ  ø?ðð ÿðxø?ÿÁð  ƒÿÿàÿþÿÿàþþÿÿƒÿÿÿÿÿÁø?ðð ?ÿð|ø?ÿÁðüƒÿÿàÿþÿÿüþþÿÿƒÿÿÿÿÿø?ððÿÿð~ø?ÿÁðøƒÿÿàÿþÿÿÿ€þþÿÿÿÿÿÿÿƒø?ððÿÿð~ø?ÿÁðø?ƒÿÿðüÿÿÿÀþþÿÿÿÿÿÿÿƒø?ððÿÿðø?ÿðø?ƒÿÿðüÿÿÿàþþÿþÿÿÿÿƒÿø?ððÿðø?ÿø?ð?ƒÿÿð?øÿÿÿàþþÿþÿÿÿÿƒþøð?ðþðø?ÿø?àÿÿøð?ÿüàþþÿüÿÿÿÿüø€€øðÀø?üøÀÿøøøà?ÿøÀþþÇøÿÿÿÿÀ0ü    € ðàx?€ü ÿÀ   ü ~  8þþ€ ?ÿÿÿÿà ü   À ?ðà8? þ ÿÀ @ þ  þ  8 þþ€ ÿÿÿÿð þ  À ÿðð8? ÿ ÿà àÿ þ  > þþ€ ÿÿÿÿÿüÿÿ€€ÿðÿðø? ÿÿÀÿøøÿÿàÿÿÿÀÿÿÿÿðÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿðø?ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿðü?ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿðþ ?ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿðÿ ?ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿðÿ ?ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿðÿ€?ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿðÿÀ?ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿðÿÀ?ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿðÿà?ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿðÿð?ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿðÿð?ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ
```

So I have  tried to use the font manually in prn file.
Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change encoding of prn file to ANSI. You can easily do this with Notepad++ Encoding -> Convert to ANSI.
From my experience all xpml code is unnecessary.
Also I suggest TSPL manual http://www.tscprinters.com/cms/upload/download_en/TSPL_TSPL2_Programming.pdf